# how to fetch multiple data from database to label in C# windows application

Tags: c#

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(
        "select  CustomerName,CompanyName,ContactNo from tbl_LeadFollowUp where WorkType='internet shopping'", con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(ds);
    da.Fill(dt);

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        textBox1.Text = (row["CompanyName"].ToString());
        textBox2.Text = (row["CustomerName"].ToString());
        label2.Text = (row["ContactNo"].ToString());
     }
     con.close();
}
```

Comment: Learn databinding and how to use databound control

Comment: Is the question here "how do I display multiple rows in the UI?" - because... you're probably going to want a grid of some kind (`DataGridView` etc) to put the results in...

Comment: I'm not sure if you are asking for this but,   `label2.Text += (row["ContactNo"].ToString());`. If you want to show multiple data in label (as you told in the question) use this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [DataGridview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z(v=vs.110).aspx) for binding the multiple data from Database to UI.

You can't iterate multiple data to single lable. It will get overwrite not append

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  con.Open();
  SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select  CustomerName,CompanyName,ContactNo from tbl_LeadFollowUp where WorkType='internet shopping'", con);
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  da.Fill(ds);
  da.Fill(dt);
  dataGridView1.DataSource = da;
  dataGridView1.DataMember = "Lead";
  con.close();
}
```